# Using JOIN in UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that have identical structure:

`|   term (varchar(50) utf8_bin)    |     count (bigint(11))    |`

One table is called "big_table" and the other one "small_table". Big table has ~10M rows and small_table has 75k.

I want to update small_table, so the count column will be filled from the big_table.
I tried this:

```
UPDATE small_table b SET counter = (SELECT c.counter
                                 FROM big_table c
                                 WHERE c.term = b.term)
WHERE term = (SELECT c.term
              FROM big_table c
              WHERE c.term = b.term);
```

But it is only updating one row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you only need a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE small_table b 
  JOIN big_table c
    ON c.term = b.term
SET b.counter = c.counter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `WHERE` part at all:

```
UPDATE 
    small_table b 
SET 
    counter = 
        ISNULL
        (
            (
                SELECT c.counter
                FROM big_table c
                WHERE c.term = b.term
            ), 
            0
        )
```

Think about this way:

`UPDATE` every row in `small_table` and `SET` column `counter` to the `counter` value found in `big_table` record `WHERE` value of `term` is equals to `term` in `small_table`. If nothing is found in `big_table` then just set `counter` to `0`.

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm getting this error: "ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'counter' cannot be null"

Comment: This is because there is no corresponding record in `big_table`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will help you

```
          UPDATE small_table SET counter = c.counter
          FROM big_table c INNER JOIN small_table b ON c.term = b.term
```